# Observable with multiple MatTableDataSource

Tags: angular, observable, mat-table

I have an angular 6 application which displays multiple mat-tables in a page. 
Here is how the json looks like.

```
"job-detail": 
    {
      "JobId": "480960",
      "jobDocMetadata":
        [
            {
                "seq": "1",
                "docID": "524126",
                "type": "Print",
                "title": "Sample"               
            },
            {
                "seq": "2",
                "docID": "524125",
                "type": "Print",
                "title": "Sample"               
            }           
        ],
        "jobStatusHistory":
        [
            {
                "date": "12-04-2018 12:47:16 CST",
                "code": "200",
                "jobStatus": "Job Undergoing Composition",
                "description": "received a new job"
            },
            {
                "date": "12-04-2018 12:48:14 CST",
                "code": "315",
                "jobStatus": "Job successfully delivered",
                "description": "job finished,"
            }           
        ],
        }
```

I'm trying to display the data from jobDocMetadata and jobStatusHistory in 2 separate mat-tables in the same page.
Here is the service which gets the data from a rest service.

```
findJobDetail(jobID: number): Observable<JobDetail> {
    return this.httpClient.get<JobDetail>(`${this.JOB_DETAIL_URL}`, customHttpOptions).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`Found Job`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<any>('findJobDetail')),
    );
  }
```

And this is the component code so far, subscribing to the observable and it's working fine.

```
     public jobDetailObs: Observable<JobDetail>;
     public jobDetail: JobDetail;
     jobDocMetadataDS: MatTableDataSource<JobDocMetadata>;
     jobStatusHistoryDS: MatTableDataSource<JobStatusHistory>;
     @ViewChildren(MatSort)
     sort = new QueryList<MatSort>();

      this.apiService.findJobDetail(this.id).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.jobDetail = data as JobDetail;

        this.jobDocMetadataDS = new MatTableDataSource(this.jobDetail.jobDocMetadata);
        this.jobDocMetadataDS.sort = this.sort.toArray()[0];

        this.jobStatusHistoryDS = new MatTableDataSource(this.jobDetail.jobStatusHistory);
        this.jobStatusHistoryDS.sort = this.sort.toArray()[1];
             }
        )
```

Here is the template sample.

```
<h2 class="mat-h2 subheader">Job Document Metadata</h2>
    <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <mat-table #table [dataSource]="jobDocMetadataDS" matSort>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="seq">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Seq </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.seq}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="docID">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Doc ID </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.docID}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
```

I'm trying to modify this code to use async pipes, since it has been prefered over subscribing to an observable.  For this, I'm trying to bind my datasources to the Observable.

```
this.jobDetailObs = this.apiService.findJobDetail(this.id).pipe(share());
```

So my question is how can I bind 2 datasources to an Observable of JobDetail.
I couldn't bind Observable directly to the data source since the data I need is inside JobDetail. So I'm thinking to convert the Observable of JobDetail to a JobDetail object (jobDetailObs to jobDetail) to achieve this mapping. Is this the best way to do it and if so, how can I achieve it ?

Comment: It's hard to figure out how you're using the `jobDetailObs`, you're not subscribing to it - I'm guessing you are using an `async pipe` in the template?

Comment: @Drenai added more details of the existing code and expected behavior. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

on before mounting the component, you should create two observables from findJobDetail

```
const findJobDetail$ = this.apiService.findJobDetail(this.id).pipe(share())

this.jobDocMetadataDS$ = findJobDetail$.pipe(map(<map from job detail to doc meta>))
this.jobStatusHistoryDS$ = findJobDetail$.pipe(map(<map from job detail to status history>))
```

and use in template with async pipe